# RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA vs TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

Tags: ssl, encryption

Is there a difference between RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA and TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, and for my information, any cipher and its TLS_ prepended version?

Answer (score 1):

In RFC 6101 (SSL 3.0) all cipher suites start with "SSL_".

In RFC 2246 (TLS 1.0) all cipher suites start with "TLS_", however the two-byte identifier of the cipher suites are identical to the cipher suites of SSL 3.0 (of course only for ciphers which exist in SSL and TLS).

Therefore I assume that the cipher suite without prepended TLS was used in a context where both protocols (SSL and TLS) are used.